# Need to change yaml file to properties file

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Im trying to convert my yaml file to properties file using ansible. 
I have yaml file like this

```
class: tenth
hobbies: playing
name:
  first.last: jake.l
```

I need to convert above yaml lines to properties file.
Like,

```
class = tenth
hobbies = playing
name.first.last = jake.l
```

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_lookups.html#the-ini-file-lookup) is an example. From what you've said I'm guessing it should be like

```
user.class=tenth
user.hobbies=playing
user.name.first_last=jake.l
```